# How do I return generic error pages based on different urls using nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use nginx error_page directive ([link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page)) to show error pages.

This is my code so far:

```
error_page 404 /site/404.html;

location /site/404.html {
    try_files $uri =404;
    break;
}
```

But what I really want is show this 404.html page only if the url is www.example.com/example.  And not show this 404.html error page if the url is only www.example.com.  Is it possible to achieve this behavior using error_page directive?

Comment: The `error_page` directive may appear inside a `location` block. So you can specify which locations (or URIs) use the custom page.

Comment: @RichardSmith if I add error_page in a location block then it doesn't load the original location.  Page just errors out.

Comment: @RichardSmith what syntax do I need to use if the only difference I want is error_page directive.

Comment: Yes. That is [how location blocks work](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html). You could use it inside an `if` block [but I would not advise that](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). You might structure your configuration file so that common directives are [included from another file](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include).